# How to check if an object can be instantiated using PHP

Tags: php, object, instantiation

I can't do this but wondering what would work:

```
is_object(new Memcache){
   //assign memcache object    
   $memcache = new Memcache;
   $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
   $memcache->get('myVar');
}
else{
   //do database query to generate myVar variable
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [**class_exists**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php)

```
if (class_exists('Memcache')){
   //assign memcache object    
   $memcache = new Memcache;
   $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);
   $memcache->get('myVar');
}
else{
   //do database query to generate myVar variable
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `class_exists()` to check if a class exists, but it will not return if you can instantiate that class!

One of the reasons you can't, might be that it is an abstract class. To check for that you should do something like this *after* you check for `class_exists()`.

This might be impossible (having an abstract class, not checking for it) for above example, but in other situations might be giving you headaches :)

```
//first check if exists, 
if (class_exists('Memcache')){
   //there is a class. but can we instantiate it?
   $class = new ReflectionClass('Memcache') 
   if( ! $class->isAbstract()){
       //dingdingding, we have a winner!
    }
}
```

Comment: Even though other answers provide _sufficient_ solution, this should be the accepted answer for going a crucial step further

Answer (score 0):

Check out `class_exists()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `class_exists` function to see if a class exists or not.

See more in the manual: [class_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php)

Answer (score 0):

The [`ReflectionClass::isInstantiable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.isinstantiable.php) method checks if the class is instantiable.

```php
$reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);

if ($reflector->isInstantiable()) {
    // do something
}
```